# How to use JOIN instead of SELECT NOT IN?

Tags: sql, firebird

I have 2 tables:

- customers (customer_id, customer_name)
- documents (document_id, document_name, customer_id)

I wish to find all customers, for example, that do not have a rent contract.

I can do it such way:

```
SELECT contragent_name 
FROM contragents 
WHERE contragent_id NOT IN (SELECT contragent_id 
                            FROM documents 
                            WHERE document_name = 'Rent contract');
```

Can anybody suggest how to do it without the second select?

Comment: This is something we learn at school. Almost every SQL statement using `IN` can be rewritten to use `EXISTS` instead. The real challenge is whilst `IN` is really easy to master, `EXISTS` takes more effort. Your example is more textbook, so, the `EXISTS` syntax needed is straightforward.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: just use a left join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A left join is an alternative:

```
SELECT c.contragent_name
FROM contragents AS c
  LEFT JOIN documents d. 
         ON c.contragent_id = d.contragent_id 
        AND document_name = 'Rent contract'
WHERE d.contragent_id IS NULL;
```

But typically a NOT EXISTS condition is the most efficient way to do it (*if* there is a difference in performance - this largely depends on the actual DBMS being used).

```
SELECT c.contragent_name 
FROM contragents c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM documents d
                  WHERE d.document_name = 'Rent contract'
                    AND d.contragent_id = c.contragent_id);
```

Comment: it depends on DBMS,. on scheme (indices) and real data (are indices selective? what is the ratio between two tables sizes and between existing/non-existingrows?). Your second query spawns an extra query and and extra random-access row fetch attempt on `documents` per every `contragents` row. This might turn worse than merging two sorted full-table streams. Or, indeed, not

Answer (score 4):

Well you could rephrase your requirement using a left anti-join:

```sql
SELECT c.contragent_name
FROM contragents c
LEFT JOIN documents d
    ON d.contragent_id = c.contragent_id AND
       d.document_name = 'Rent contract'
WHERE
    d.contragent_id IS NULL;
```

However, if you were to compare the explain plan and performance of the above to your subquery approach, you might find similar things.  Actually, your current approach can easily be made performant by adding the following index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON documents (contragent_id, document_name);
```

This index should allow the rapid lookup of any record in the `contragents` table.

Answer (score 2):

Use a left join and filter where the left table key is null (but you'll still need nested query to get the subset of documents with the name Rent contract):

```
SELECT c.contragent_name
FROM contragents AS c
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT contragent_id FROM documents WHERE document_name = 'Rent contract'
) AS d ON c.id = d.contragent_id
WHERE d.id IS NULL;
```

This is sometimes referred to as a Frustrated Join.  Performance comparison for a frustrated join vs a not in selection depends upon varying factors, such as the database system in use, volume of records, sometimes database statistics/trends that a query optimizer may use...